# Javascript overriding parent classes function in child class best practices

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have a parent base class that sets up some common functions that are used in the child class, something like this:

```
class BaseClass() {

    constructor(someValue){
        this.value = value
    }
    methodToBeOverridden(){
        //This is implemented in the child class.
    }
}
```

I want to know what is common practice for methods that are being overridden in child classes like the one above. Currently, I just leave a comment with nothing in it. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending for `methodToBeOverridden()` to be implemented in classes inheriting `BaseClass`, you can throw in the parent.

```
methodToBeOverridden() {
    throw new Error('This method needs to be implemented!');
}
```

but really I'm not sure I see the point in this - if you simply do not define `methodToBeOverridden()` in `BaseClass` and call it on some child instance, an error will be thrown anyway since the method isn't defined.

---

TypeScript has the concept of [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes), which more appropriately solves your problem.

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    constructor(public value: any) {
      //
    }

    abstract methodToBeOverridden(): void;
}
```

Comment: So with the way you have it above, the error will be thrown if the child classes don't override that method?

Comment: What you've said is correct, but just to be absolutely clear, it only throws when calling `methodToBeOverridden()` on a child class that has not implemented the method.